# find - Logical operators

Tags: command-line, permissions, find

I want `find` shows me the result with excluding permissions 660 AND files.

I.e. it has to show me files that have no permission 660 and all directories.

I run:

```
find "/path/to/dir" -not \( -perm 660 -a -type f \) -exec ls -lA {} \;
```

But it shows me files with permissions 660.

Result:

```
-rw-rw---- 1 root root  124832 Dec 21  2018 READ.ME.txt
```

**IMPORTANT!**

I exactly need `-not` and group `\( ... \)`.

Comment: if you use `+` instead of `\;` will keep `ls` formating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `-not \( -perm 660 -a -type f \)`  will match a directory, and so `ls -lA` will be run on that directory and show you all the files in it.

If you want to see the results of `find`, don't use `ls` without the `-d` option. Or use `-ls`.

```
% find foo -not \( -perm 660 -a -type f \) -exec ls -lA {} \;
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 muru muru 0 Nov 18 19:20 READ.ME.txt
-rw-rw---- 1 muru muru 0 Nov 18 19:21 READ.ME.txt1
-rw-r--r-- 1 muru muru 0 Nov 18 19:20 foo/READ.ME.txt
% find foo -not \( -perm 660 -a -type f \) -exec ls -lAd {} \;
drwxr-xr-x 2 muru muru 80 Nov 18 19:21 foo
-rw-r--r-- 1 muru muru 0 Nov 18 19:20 foo/READ.ME.txt
% find foo -not \( -perm 660 -a -type f \) -ls;           
      262      0 drwxr-xr-x   2 muru     muru           80 Nov 18 19:21 foo
      263      0 -rw-r--r--   1 muru     muru            0 Nov 18 19:20 foo/READ.ME.txt
```